# Последовательный вывод в консоль на C++

Tags: c++, вывод, ввод

Пишу на C++ программку.
Требуется, чтобы строка выводилась с паузами, т.е. буква, задержка, буква, задержка и т.д.
Подскажите, как это написать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Так и делать. Букву, задержку... Букву, задержку...

Comment: @Harry, а как сделать саму задержку?

Comment: Используйте любую доступную функцию `sleep`.

Comment: Сейчас набросаю...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, так:

```
void outDelay(const std::string& s, int ms)
{
    for(auto c: s)
    {
        std::cout << c;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    outDelay("Hello",500);
}
```

Comment: Ругается на this_thread: error: |'std::this_thread' has not been declared|

Comment: Добавьте #include <thread> и #include <chrono>

Comment: Это C++11, если компилятор более старый - пользуйтесь API операционной системы.

Comment: А можно как-то обойтись средствами C++03?

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну... Откровенно говоря, если не использовать APO, то кроме как в цикле опрашивать `clock()`, пока не пройдет нужное время, вариантов не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

способов много, можно задерживать поток, а можно и нет, например так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>    

using namespace std::chrono;

void timedCout(const std::string& str, double ms)
{
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << str[i++];
    while (i < str.size())
    {
        high_resolution_clock::time_point now = high_resolution_clock::now();
        duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(now - t1);

        if (time_span.count() >= ms)
        {
            t1 = now;
            std::cout << str[i++];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string str = "timedcout";
    timedCout(str, 0.6f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не надо молотить цикл вхолостую!

Comment: @alexolut да неужели, и сколько холостых итераций тут по вашему ?

Comment: добавьте счетчик в while, да посчитайте